# MySQL syntax error for INSERT

Tags: mysql, c, insert, syntax-error

This precise code was working before on my old machine, but I'm getting this error spat back at me (on Mac OSX 10.7).

The C code is:

```
printf("%s\n",query);

if (mysql_query(conn,query)){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn)); 
}
```

The output is:

```
INSERT INTO comment (unum,cat_subject,cat_major,cat_minor,unmod) 
 VALUES (1,1,1,0,'The cat was lazy.') 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
 for the right syntax to use near ','The cat was lazy.')' at line 1
```

The original `printf` statements creates two lines of text, but I've wrapped them for readability.

It all looks fine to me! The following works in PHP for the same table (with the correct `bindParam` statements):

```
$STH=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO comment (unum,cat_subject,cat_major,cat_minor,unmod) VALUES (:u,:s,:ma,:mi,:t)");
```

What's wrong?

(BTW: I tried it with `"` instead of `'` but that made no difference.)

Comment: Maybe the new version requires a `;` at the end of the query? (unlikely, but who knows). Or maybe your table name is a keyword and should be changed to `\`comment\``?

Comment: The table works fine when called by PHP/AJAX, so its name must be OK. And this works fine in PHP, so I don't think it needs a semicolon: `$STH=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO comment (unum,cat_subject,cat_major,cat_minor,unmod) VALUES (:u,:s,:ma,:mi,:t)");`. :)

Comment: Is there a non-printable character in `query` after the `0`?

Comment: @eggyal Yes, I suspect that may be it. I tried `char query1[] = "INSERT INTO comment (unum,cat_subject,cat_major,cat_minor,unmod) VALUES (1,1,1,1,'Test comment')"; strcpy(p_query,query1);` and it worked. The other query was built by inserting the values using statements like `strcat(p_query, subject);`  How can I ensure a variable like `subject` doesn't have junk in it?

Comment: If you don't *know* what `subject` contains, I'd suggest using the [prepared statement API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) to pass your variables over to MySQL as parameters (which obviously protect against SQL injection too).

Comment: @eggyal I thought I did! Add an answer (instead of a comment) for your non-printable character suggestion, and I'll tick it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

It appears that you may have non-printable characters in `query`, probably after the `0` character.  Try hexdumping the string's bytes to see if anything is suspicious:

```
char* c;
for (c=query; *c; c++) printf("%02x",*c);
```

Should you be concatenating into your SQL the unknown contents of variables, I'd strongly recommend using MySQL's [prepared statement API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) to pass your variables to MySQL as parameters in order to avoid SQL injection; this will also perform basic type-conversion of such parameters to the destination column types - if you need more control over the cleansing of your variables, you will need to perform such in your application prior to passing the parameters to MySQL.

Comment: I changed it to `printf("%02x %c \n",*c,*c);` to make it easier :)  And I found `31 1 2c , 31 1 2c , 32 2 2c , 31 1 7f [criminal here] 2c ,` (line breaks removed). I am creating the value myself, so junk has crept in. How do you do a simple regex equivalent to ensure there are only numeric elements? The solutions seem overly complex. (I'm not trying to resist the API model, but I don't understand how it is to be done - there are no examples on the page ;)  I might ask this as another question if you're too busy. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nick: You would be wise to first understand *how* such a character crept in, then decide what action is appropriate (should it be replaced with something else?  stripped out/ignored?  what about any characters in the same field that follow it - should they also be ignored?).  Make those decisions first, then post as a separate question (only because my C is incredibly rusty though!).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll do as you advise. I build the fields character by character in most cases, so inserting a filter should be quite do-able.